# Trying to figure out why i cannot parse my JSON file

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, file, syntax-error

I can not figure out where my error is with in this JSON file. i know there is one somewhere because when trying to parse it. i get the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token J i was wondering if you guys could help me by taking a look and seeing if you see my problem i have been researching all night on this one and i am still un able to find the error. Someone from the community helped me find one but it is still not working i am parsing the JSON like so

```
var obj = JSON.parse("JSON.json");
```

and here is the JSON

```
{
"Subbackground":{"direction": "to bottom", "Color1": " #a90329 0%", "Color2": "#8f0222 44%", "Color3": "#6d0019 100%"},
"ButtonBG": {"direction":"to bottom", "Color1": "#216332 5%", "Color2": "#5cbf2a 100%"},
"ButtonHov": {"direction":"to bottom", "Color1": "#5cbf2a 5%", "Color2": "#216332 100%"},
"textColor":"#ffffff",
"BorderSubColor":"#a90329",
"ButtonShadow":"#2f6627",
"ButtonBShawdow":"#3dc21b",
"BorderMain":"#18ab29",
"Sub1":"steaknshake", "urlPath1":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Sub2":"steaknshake", "urlPath2":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Sub3":"steaknshake", "urlPath3":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Sub4":"steaknshake", "urlPath4":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Sub5":"steaknshake", "urlPath5":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Sub6":"steaknshake", "urlPath6":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Sub7":"steaknshake", "urlPath7":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Sub8":"steaknshake", "urlPath8":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Sub9":"steaknshake", "urlPath9":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Sub10":"steaknshake", "urlPath10":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Pizza":"steaknshake", "urlPathP":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Berger":"steaknshake", "urlPathB":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Lobster":"steaknshake", "urlPathL":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Chicken":"steaknshake", "urlPathCN":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Shrimp":"steaknshake", "urlPathSP":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"BLT":"steaknshake", "urlPathB":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Salmon":"steaknshake", "urlPathSN":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"CatFish":"steaknshake", "urlPathCF":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Steak":"steaknshake", "urlPathSK":"http://www.steaknshake.com/",
"Crab":"steaknshake", "urlPathCB":"http://www.steaknshake.com/"
}
```

Comment: `JSON.parse()` takes a JSON string as a parameter, not a filename. You'll have to load the file first with other means.

Comment: I am looking up things like how to load a JSON file and $.getJSON(); but i am in able to find what i am looking for could you point me in the right direction

Comment: Sure, try [here](http://google.com). You just marked the answer correct so the problem is solved?

Comment: Already tried Google every developers best friend but if my problem has yet to be solved then why mark the answer and also i believe i marked the answer below correct.

Comment: Yes, you marked the answer correct. Why did you do so if it didn't solve your problem?

Comment: as i said in the edited question it helped fix one problem but another one came up so i had it un marked but then re marked it because you asked me to

Comment: I didn't ask you to do that. You misunderstood my comment.

Comment: I apologize i did miss read your comment that is my bad. For me the question is still un answered he did indeed answer my first question but i edited the question because i was still stuck i am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the last line, you haven't closed the quotes around the `urlPath` value:

```
"Crab":"steaknshake", "urlPath":"http://www.steaknshake.com/"
                                                            ^ was missing
```

For future reference you can use [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to test for valid JSON and find errors.